# Converting Degrees Minutes Seconds to Decimal Degrees for coordinates?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, convert, coordinates, degrees-minutes-seconds

I have a list of coordinates I'm trying to put into a csv and then convert to points in ArcMap. I tried converting them to decimal degrees because at first they appear to be in DMS. When I plotted the converted points, they ended up in a completely different area.

Can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing incorrectly?

Here's a sample of the coordinates:

```
+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
|  DMS_Lat   | DMS_Long  |  Latitude   |  Longitude  |
+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| 29°0.1'N   | 81°31.2'W | 29.00166667 | 81.52       |
| 28°3.2'N   | 81°56.0'W | 28.05333333 | 81.93333333 |
| 27°47.3'N  | 81°53.3'W | 27.78833333 | 81.88833333 |
| 25°34.6'N  | 80°27.2'W | 25.57666667 | 80.45333333 |
| 28°44.1'N  | 80°45.4'W | 28.735      | 80.75666667 |
| 26°8.7'N   | 80°26.6'W | 26.145      | 80.44333333 |
| 27°29'N    | 82°35'W   | 27.48333333 | 82.58333333 |
+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Since the longitudes are west, the decimal degrees longitude needs to be negative. Likewise, if the latitudes were south, then the converted latitudes would need to be multiplied by -1.

Comment: @Tom, you're absolutely right. Thank you! I knew I was missing something.

Comment: Is this resolved?  If so, please add an answer and mark it as correct.

Comment: @Tom Would you be able to write your comment up as an answer, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When converting from DD⁰ MM' SS", you must remember that S latitudes will become negative and that W longitudes will become negative. Simply multiply the converted lat and/or lon by -1.